# I get logged out of SO when I visit a certain website in another window

Tags: support, logout

Stack Overflow logs me out every time I leave the *`www.regex101.com`* regex test page. It's when I'm closing the window and have to click ***Leave this page*** button.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: I don't see how leaving an unrelated site could log you ot of so? What leave this page button do you mean? You will have to give more detail here or I don't see how anyone can help you. I cannot recreate this

Comment: @MarkKirby - Oh, you can try it yourself. Go there, enter a regex, test it. When you try to close the _page_ (window), there is a highlighted wide square divided into two buttons, top and bottom. Top says `Leave this page`, bottom says `Stay on this page`. I'm using IE11. I can post a screen shot if you'd like.

Comment: I manged to get the leave this page button, from the screen test but am still logged in to so. Seems it could be an IE issue most likly, as the browser was abandoned in 2016(?), I doubt the devs here would even entertain it. You should REALLY change from that dead and unsecure browser. I used Firefox and it was fine.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I've entertained switching brow's but I hate learning new quirks. Even though I _hate_ IE, I seem to know how to work around it. So, what do you mean by the `browser was abandoned in 2016` ? By the SO dev's ?

Comment: No by Microsoft, abandoned was a strong word, more like it is on life support as they move to edge

Comment: Actually it was more like January 2018, when Windows 8.1 ended mainstream support (Windows 8.1 can't run Edge). (cc @MarkKirby)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog fyi, Win 7 EOL is in 2020, so IE is not yet dead, yet

Comment: @yagmoth555 And 8.1 in 2023, but *mainstream* support ended for 8.1 in January of this year, which means no more *feature* updates after that.

Comment: I just tried this on IE11 and it didn't log me out. Does this happen for you if you try it in InPrivate Browsing?

Comment: @Mehrdad - I don't know, I'm logged into SO already. I just normal open a new instance of IE11 to http://www.regex101.com, either from right clicking an existing _demo link_ and click open in a new window, put in a regex, or modify existing one, then either save or modify, then click the save/share. Then I try to close the instance of IE11, get the _leave/stay on page_ message (from website?), click _Leave_. Window closes, I click on the SO window, try to edit or continue what I was doing. Presto, I'm logged out. I can repeat this %100 of the time.

Comment: @sln: Yeah I get what you're doing, I'm saying try it in InPrivate Browsing mode and see if it happens there.